# Spark SQL Thrift Server on CDH 5.3.0

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera-cdh

I am trying to use CDH 5.3.0 to run Spark's Thrift Server. I'm trying to follow the Spark SQL instructions, but I can't even get the `--help` option to run successfully. In the output below, it dies because it can't find the HiveServer2 class.

```
$ /usr/lib/spark/sbin/start-thriftserver.sh --help
Usage./sbin/start-thriftserver [options] [thrift server options]
Options:
  --master MASTER_URL         spark://host:port, mesos://host:port, yarn, or local.
  --deploy-mode DEPLOY_MODE   Whether to launch the driver program locally ("client") or
                              on one of the worker machines inside the cluster ("cluster")
                              (Default: client).
  --class CLASS_NAME          Your application's main class (for Java / Scala apps).
  --name NAME                 A name of your application.
  --jars JARS                 Comma-separated list of local jars to include on the driver
                              and executor classpaths.
  --py-files PY_FILES         Comma-separated list of .zip, .egg, or .py files to place
                              on the PYTHONPATH for Python apps.
  --files FILES               Comma-separated list of files to be placed in the working
                              directory of each executor.

  --conf PROP=VALUE           Arbitrary Spark configuration property.
  --properties-file FILE      Path to a file from which to load extra properties. If not
                              specified, this will look for conf/spark-defaults.conf.

  --driver-memory MEM         Memory for driver (e.g. 1000M, 2G) (Default: 512M).
  --driver-java-options       Extra Java options to pass to the driver.
  --driver-library-path       Extra library path entries to pass to the driver.
  --driver-class-path         Extra class path entries to pass to the driver. Note that
                              jars added with --jars are automatically included in the
                              classpath.

  --executor-memory MEM       Memory per executor (e.g. 1000M, 2G) (Default: 1G).

  --help, -h                  Show this help message and exit
  --verbose, -v               Print additional debug output

 Spark standalone with cluster deploy mode only:
  --driver-cores NUM          Cores for driver (Default: 1).
  --supervise                 If given, restarts the driver on failure.

 Spark standalone and Mesos only:
  --total-executor-cores NUM  Total cores for all executors.

 YARN-only:
  --executor-cores NUM        Number of cores per executor (Default: 1).
  --queue QUEUE_NAME          The YARN queue to submit to (Default: "default").
  --num-executors NUM         Number of executors to launch (Default: 2).
  --archives ARCHIVES         Comma separated list of archives to be extracted into the
                              working directory of each executor.

Thrift server options:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hive/service/server/HiveServer2
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.service.server.HiveServer2
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 2):

As indicated by the error, the class is not in the classpath. Unfortunately, setting the CLASSPATH environment variable won't work. The only solution that I could find was to edit `/usr/lib/spark/bin/compute-classpath.sh` and add this line (it can go just about anywhere, but put it one line from the end to make it clear that it's an addition):

```
CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:/usr/lib/hive/lib/*"
```

Cloudera's [release notes for 5.3.0](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/cdh_rn_new_in_530.html) explicitly state "Spark SQL remains an experimental and unsupported feature in CDH", so it's not surprising that tweaks like this may be needed. Also, [this response](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/d/msg/cdh-user/AcgBmZexCuo/uK8dJgydbasJ) to a similar problem in CDH 5.2 suggests that the Hive jars are deliberately excluded by Cloudera for size reasons.

Comment: Now in Spark1.4, there is no file named `compute-classpath.sh`, where shall I add the CLASSPATH?

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem but I solved it in another way.

The cloudera CDH version was not 5.3.0 it was some version prior to that version so you will find the paths little different.

Simply the solution was to replace the spark-assembly-**.jar file that shipped with cloudera CDH by another version.

I downloaded spark from its official download page. The version I have downloaded was built for hadoop 2.4 and later. Extracting the downloaded file and look for spark-assembly-**.jar.

In the cloudera installation, I looked for the same file and I found it under that path **/usr/lib/spark/libe/spark-assembly--.jar**

The previous path actually was a symlink to the actual file. I uploaded the jar from spark download to the same path and make the symlink point to the new jar (**ln -f -s target link**).

Every thing works fine with me.

Comment: Did you have to rebuild Spark?

Comment: AFAIR no I did exactly what is described in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/lib/spark/bin/compute-classpath.sh` sets `CLASSPATH="$SPARK_CLASSPATH"`. On CDH using parcels you can add the hive jars to `SPARK_CLASSPATH` like this:

```
SPARK_CLASSPATH=$(ls -1 /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hive/lib/*.jar | sed -e :a  -e 'N;s/\n/:/;ta') /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/sbin/start-thriftserver.sh --help
```

Comment: compute-classpath.sh doesn't exist in CDH 5.5 .. was it renamed or just removed? other workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Instructions from Cloudera Community forum
http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/CDH-5-5-does-not-have-Spark-Thrift-Server/m-p/41849#M1758 :

```
git clone https://github.com/cloudera/spark.git

cd spark

./make-distribution.sh -DskipTests \
  -Dhadoop.version=2.6.0-cdh5.7.0 \
  -Phadoop-2.6 \
  -Pyarn \
  -Phive -Phive-thriftserver \
  -Pflume-provided \
  -Phadoop-provided \
  -Phbase-provided \
  -Phive-provided \
  -Pparquet-provided
```

-Phive and -Phive-thriftserver are the key pieces there.

There is a request to add Spark Thrift Server
https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/DISTRO-817 
please vote up if you want to see that in CDH.